# Revision hardware requirements

Tags: system-requirements

I have minimal experience with Ubuntu but now it's time to learn.

I know from previous experience some older computers my not support the latest version. I am sure a page is some where that would tell what I need to know. Could someone give me the link please? I am looking at a older Dell latitude laptop with 98 on it to serve has a starting point learn with. I am guessing the latest and greatest will not work on it....

Also next question, I am also looking at learning Apache software... I am thinking I have seen Apache is included or something like that.... I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer's memory size is the main selection factor and your processor's ability to run 64-bit operating systems, the second.  As for the version, newer versions normally add support for new hardware.  It's a very rare case that they remove support for older.

If your memory size is 1GB, then your only option is a 32-bit Lubuntu or Xubuntu flavor if you want to have a really functional operating system without very frequent swapping issues.

If it's 2GB, you can use any 32-bit flavor.

If it's 4GB you can switch to 64-bit versions provided that your processor supports it.

Comment: The thanks, I am not sure what it has in it. But I also have a tower I forgot about that I may convert over.